# Adding 'X' button with working javascript next to the text field

Tags: javascript, html

i'm not familiar (at all) with JavaScript and i googled and found an awesome demo tutorial for adding text-fields with js. This is the [link](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/). I got it working but it lacks one feature - removing text field. I also downloaded awesome icon set to put it next to the button, but could anyone describe how to remove text field by pressing the button?

This is the default javascript from page (i modified the entry part a bit to fit my needs)

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 65;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Nimi " + (counter + 1) + " <input type='text' name='myInputs[]' class='field'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

and this is the html part

```
<form method="POST">
        <script src=form.js></script>
        <div id="dynamicInput">
            Nimi 1<input type="text" name="myInputs[]" class="field">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Add another text input"     onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
    </form>
```

It's easy to add button next to it but could someone make a quick js code to remove the text field with clicking on the button next to it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure Javascript solution, without any JQuery. What you want to do is create another function, set the last child of your parent div to a variable and then remove the child. Don't forget to reduce your counter!

```
function removeInput(divName) {
     var lastDiv = document.getElementById(divName).lastChild;
      document.getElementById(divName).removeChild(lastDiv);
      counter--;
}
```

Here is the code for the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove text input" onClick="removeInput('dynamicInput');">
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding a component to the DOM you should give it an id. When you want to remove a certain component you can refer to it with the id.

```
newDiv.id = 'soCool'; //when creating the component.
$('#soCool').remove(); //using jQuery
```

You could also set the class of the component so that when you have added multiple components of the same class, you can delete them all at same time.

```
newDiv.class = 'soCoolClass';
otherNewDiv.class = 'soCoolClass';
$('.soCoolClass').remove(); //this will remove newDiv and otherNewDiv
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 65;
function addInput(divName){
    if (counter == limit)  {
         alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
         var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
         newdiv.innerHTML = "Nimi " + (counter + 1) + " <input type='text' name='myInputs[]' class='field'> <button onClick='removeInput()'>Remove</button>";
         document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
         counter++;
    }
}
function removeInput(){
    event.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(event.target.parentNode);
    counter--;
}
```